# Entity Framework, Tasks, and async/await

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, asynchronous

I feel a bit embarrassed asking this, but I've many articles/blog posts/tutorials and watched several YouTube videos but I still don't fully understand the best practices of using async/await.

I am trying to get a WPF Window to load some data (using Entity Framework 6.1.3) when the form is loaded. However, despite what I believe to be the proper use of Tasks and async/await, the UI is blocked until the load is complete. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I do not know where or why.

```
public class FormUI
{
    protected FormUI()
    {
        this.Loaded += OnWindowLoaded;
    }

    protected virtual async void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bvm = DataContext as ViewModel;

        // Due to the way I instantiate the UI, bvm is never null
        await bvm.LoadData();
    }
}


public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    /* The PropNotify object is inherited from BaseViewModel and is just an easy method
     * for me to implement PropertyChanged so the WPF bindings are updated. (It's 
     * a glorified OnPropertyChanged).
     */

    // This property is bound as the ItemSource of a ComboBox on the UI
    private List<ComputerBrand> _computerBrands;
    public List<ComputerBrand> ComputerBrands
    {
        get { return _computerBrands; }
        set { PropNotify.SetProperty(ref _computerBrands, value); }
    }

    // This property is bound as the SelectedItem of the ComboBox
    private ComputerBrand _selectedComputerBrand;
    public ComputerBrand SelectedComputerBrand
    {
        get { return _selectedComputerBrand; }
        set { PropNotify.SetProperty(ref _selectedComputerBrand, value); }
    }

    // Implements abstract method in BaseViewModel
    public override async Task LoadData()
    {
        IsLoading = true;

        await Task.Delay(3000); // used for debugging

        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
            ComputerBrands = await context.ComputerBrands.ToListAsync();

        SelectedComputerBrand = ComputerBrands.FirstOrDefault();

        IsLoading = false;
    }
}
```

I'm looking at the responsiveness of the UI as a measure of whether this works or not. Basically as soon as the UI loads, I drag it across my screen, taking note of when the UI freezes. During the `Task.Delay` call, the UI is fully responsive and it doesn't stall at all. However, as soon as the 3 second delay is over, the UI freezes until the info is loaded from the database.

What's especially confusing for me is that the biggest bottleneck seems to be the `SelectedComputerBrand = ComputerBrands.FirstOrDefault()` call, *after* (I think) all the data is loaded. That should be near instant, shouldn't it?

NOTE: There's not a whole lot of data to retrieve, maybe 15 records or so.

TL;DR: Not sure why my implementation of Task async/await is incorrect, and I'm not sure how to go about debugging it.

Comment: I am not sure that you can turn the event `OnWindowLoaded` into an async method. Maybe that is the problem? You could test it with just having an `await Task.Delay(1000);` in that method body and nothing else.

Comment: `List<ComputerBrand> _computerBrands;` should be an observable collection if you are data-binding it. Though that doesn't explain your main problem, I would like to eliminate it from the possibilities.

Comment: Normally we make collection properties read-only. But again, this is a minor issue that shouldn't explain your problem.

Comment: One list bit of irrelevant advice. Don't use `DataContext as ViewModel` if you know that it will always be `null` or a `ViewModel`. Other people reading your code will be confused, as that syntax says "this can be any type, but I only care about this type at the moment"

Comment: How is your xaml binding defined? Have you set IsAsync=True on the binding?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to diagnose the issue. However, you certainly could use the debugger and/or trace output to figure out how much time is spent between each call in the method. This would confirm your apparent suspicion that the delay is in `FirstOrDefault()`. It's entirely possible that the `ToListAsync()` method doesn't do the work you think it does, and instead data retrieval is deferred until the enumeration contents are actually materialized by the `FirstOrDefault()` call. If so, you'll need to put that in a `Task` and await it too.

Comment: @EliArbel Yes, there is still a hang if I don't set `SelectedComputerBrand`. However, it is less of a hang than when the call is included.

Comment: @Igor Having `Task.Delay` in the `OnWindowLoaded` method works as expected, with no hangs. Similarly, if I take out everything from the view model's `LoadData` method except for `Task.Delay`, it also works as expected and without hanging.

Comment: @MageXy - I am willing to bet it has something to do with your `PropNotify.SetProperty` as this is not offloaded and runs on the UI thread. Test it by changing the properties to AutoProperties or by not setting those properties at all but still do the retrieval to local variables. It is definitely not something with `ToListAsync` as otherwise you would not be the first to report that as a bug unless there is something not standard in your DbContext implementation that you are not showing.

Comment: @EliArbel - sorry.

Comment: @EliArbel Changing that line seems to have fixed the problem, though I still don't fully understand why. In the `LoadData` method, why can I simply `await Task.Delay(3000)` without any hang (despite 3 seconds of "work") if I have to call `Task.Run` for a different method that only does about 0.5 seconds of work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be with Entity Framework's implementation of `ToListAsync()`. Looking at the code, it doesn't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which means it dispatches back to UI thread a lot.

To fix the issue, force the entire EF operation onto a thread-pool thread by using `Task.Run`:

```
ComputerBrands = await Task.Run(() => context.ComputerBrands.ToListAsync());
```

The fact that a method is asynchronous doesn't mean it's multi-threaded. Asynchrony can work even on a single thread. For example, WPF's `Dispatcher` can process instructions asynchronously (`InvokeAsync`). A `Task`-returning method can even perform all operations synchronously. It all depends on the implementation.